# How to identify patterns inside a text and categorize them

Tags: c#, regex, database, nlp, text-mining

From a table that stores medicine descriptions I need to identify the product name, strength, product quantity and pharmaceutical company of each entry. The goal is to have a copy of the table with a predefined structure.

**Current table:**
[image: current table]

**Normalized table:**
[image: normalized table]

So far I've read a little of Natural Language Processing, but I want to know another approach; I was thinking of using Regex but there are plenty of cases.

Any kind of insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I would use a combo of Regex and string operations in my code to handle this, because you have a lot of cases/scenarios to consider. I'd make the Regex fail safe and extract the 'clean' groups, like (PharmaceuticalCompanyName) and use string operations for separating the Product Name from the Strength, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your examples, your data is regular enough regexes might be a good approach. A more sophisticated approach you can try is **Named Entity Recognition** (NER). The New York Times used [CRF++](https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/) to extract ingredient information from recipes and wrote about it [here](https://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/04/09/extracting-structured-data-from-recipes-using-conditional-random-fields/).

[image: NER Example]